# locate every new appended element using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, chat

I can send message using selenium, but is it possible to create loop that can wait every time and locate every new appended element `<li class="message-out">` os that i can trigger a function using selenium in python

```
<ul class="chatView">
   <li class="message-in"> hi... </li>
   <li class="message-out"> hello... </li>
   <li class="message-in"> how are you?... </li>
</ul>


while True:
   last_message= driver.find_element_by_class_name('message-out').text
```

[image]

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? You can always run loop which periodically gets all elements and compares with elements which you get in previous loop.

Comment: while True:
   last_message= driver.find_element_by_class_name('message-out').text

I want to locate last message which is sent by other user, do that i can trigger a function

Comment: So you want to trigger a function after getting last message from other user?

Comment: yes, you got my point

Comment: keep `previous_message` and compare with `last_message` to see if it changed.

Comment: @furas if previous_message and last_message will be same , then how will compare if which one is changed

Comment: if `previous_message` and `last_message` will be same then maybe you should remeber more elements and compare few previous messages. If it doesn't remove old messages then you can get all items and check its number - `len(all_messages)`